# limit api calls while reading from stream (playframework / akka)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-stream

my task is to read a collection from mongo db (using akka streams) and for each element (document) to call some google api and enrich the element data with the result of google.

google limit api calls to 50 per second, so im using throttle like this:

```
  def processSuppliers()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Done] = {
    val suppliersSource: Source[Supplier, Future[State]] =
      suppliersCollection.find(json())
        .noCursorTimeout
        .cursor[Supplier]()
        .documentSource()
        .throttle(50, 1.second)

    suppliersSource
      .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
      .runForeach(supplier => insertEnrichedSupplier(supplier))
  }
```

the problem is: for each element im calling google 0 or more times, and there are some elements that will produce 50 - 100 calls to google, even more.

so my throttle limit is not really 50 per second...do you have any suggestion of what might solve this?

Comment: If there is no 1-to-1 mapping of DB records to API calls, you obviously have to move limiting logic to the API calls. How to do it depends on how you call API (probably in your `insertEnrichedSupplier`)

Comment: @SergGr im using play framework with and performing calls with wsClient

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be work:

```
def processSuppliers()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Done] = {
val suppliersSource: Source[Supplier, Future[State]] =
  suppliersCollection.find(json())
    .noCursorTimeout
    .cursor[Supplier]()
    .documentSource()
    .mapAsync(50)(supplier => insertEnrichedSupplier(supplier))
    .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
    .run()
}
```